# CSS Media Query applies out of range

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using following media query:

```
@media (max-width: 1439px) and (min-width: 940px) {
    ...
}
```

The strange part about it is, that when I try it on my phone or with the chrome device emulation, it always applies. No matter how small the browser/emulation window is.

Comment: did you try to write `@media screen and (max-width: 1439px) and (min-width: 940px)`

Comment: Tried it with 'all' and 'screen', same result :/

Comment: So the range you want to make it work is width -1439px and +940px width.

Comment: Try to add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> on the header.

Comment: Damn, it was actually the meta. Forgot to add it in my test file (/,.-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use media queries you must specify the type of media (`screen`)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1439px) and (min-width: 940px) {...}
```

Second thing, you must include in your html this `<meta>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```